# Windows stops playing streamed content after a while

Tags: windows

After having Windows 10 Pro 1803 running for a few days, it stops to play streamed content. It doesn't matter where that content comes from: videos in browser by Youtube and Facebook, music with Amazon Music App, ...

After a reboot everything is back for good.

What effect is it and is there any solution how to get it back to work w/o reboot?

Comment: I would first start by updating to the most current version of Win10 v1903 _(v1909 is released as a stable version in Oct)_, as random issues like this are often fixed by updating to the most recent bi-annual update _(Mar & Sep, with stable versions being released a month later)_ since each bi-annual update is similar in effect to a repair install of Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a company machine and newer versions are still not released ‍♂️

Comment: The ideal scenario would be to contact IT if your company has an IT dept.  If they don't, or this is something IT won't troubleshoot, your best bet is a forum, as this likely requires troubleshooting due to the myriad of possible causes.  I would check out [SpiceWorks](https://community.spiceworks.com/) or [MSFN](https://msfn.org/board/), as the majority members of both are highly experienced, and, at least with SpiceWorks, work in IT related fields

Answer (score 0):

Very strange: after discovering RDP issues since a few days and even more local video watching issues I uninstalled all the nVidia stuff on my machine and that fixed so far the RDP issue and also the local video watching. Presumably the streaming issue as well was fixed. We will see ...